# Need help creating a carousel creative with placement customization using the Meta API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am currently working on integrating the Meta API for creating ads on Facebook. I am specifically trying to create a carousel creative with placement customization, but I'm facing some challenges with the implementation.

I have referred to the official documentation on Meta API, specifically the section on the creative and placement asset customization. However, despite following the provided guidelines, I'm unable to create a successful carousel creative with customized assets.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, insights, or code examples that can help me understand the correct structure of the request for creating a carousel creative with placement customization using the Meta API. Specifically, I would like to know how to properly structure the asset_feed_spec, carousels, and asset_customization_rules sections.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have already attempted to implement the customization for single-image format successfully, but the issue arises when I try to extend it to carousel format. I have reviewed the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/ad-creative/asset-feed-spec/options/) but I'm still unable to figure out the correct structure for the API request.

To provide some context, here is an example of the request I'm sending:

```
{
        "asset_feed_spec": {
            "images": [
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "image_0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hash": "73ba9fe21d08f6551a6879d072819328"
                },
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "image_1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hash": "0ffd928a1f2a9994ab5268b5985cd8a2"
                },
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "image_2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hash": "bbe5de998919998a24e038fe88dfdfba"
                },
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "image_3"
                        }
                    ],
                    "hash": "1fd1162115b422551e44061895212287"
                }
            ],
            "bodies": [
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "body_0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": ""
                }
            ],
            "call_to_action_types": [
                "LEARN_MORE"
            ],
            "descriptions": [
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "description_0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": ""
                },
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "description_1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "Action"
                }
            ],
            "link_urls": [
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "link_0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "website_url": "https://test.com/",
                    "display_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "link_1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "website_url": "https://test.com/"
                }
            ],
            "titles": [
                {
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "title_0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": ""
                }
            ],
            "carousels":[
                {
                    "multi_share_end_card": false,
                    "multi_share_optimized": false,
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "CAROUSEL_0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "child_attachments": [
                        {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_0"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_0"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_0"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_1"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_0"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_0"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_2"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_0"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_0"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_3"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_0"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_0"
                           }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "multi_share_end_card": false,
                    "multi_share_optimized": false,
                    "adlabels": [
                        {
                            "name": "CAROUSEL_1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "child_attachments": [
                         {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_0"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_1"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_1"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_1"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_1"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_1"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_2"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_1"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_1"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                            "image_label": {
                                "name": "image_3"
                            },
                            "title_label":{
                                 "name": "title_0"
                            },
                            "description_label":{
                                "name": "description_1"
                           },
                           "link_url_label":{
                            "name": "link_1"
                           }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "ad_formats": [
                "CAROUSEL_IMAGE"
            ],
            "asset_customization_rules": [
                {
                    "customization_spec": {
                        "age_max": 65,
                        "age_min": 13,
                        "publisher_platforms": [
                            "instagram"
                        ],
                        "instagram_positions": [
                            "stream"
                        ]
                    },
                    "carousel_label": {
                        "name": "CAROUSEL_0"
                    },
                    "priority": 1
                },
                {
                    "customization_spec": {
                        "age_max": 65,
                        "age_min": 13
                    },
                    "carousel_label": {
                        "name": "CAROUSEL_1"
                    },
                    "priority": 2
                }
            ],
            "optimization_type": "PLACEMENT",
            "additional_data": {
                "multi_share_end_card": false,
                "is_click_to_message": false
            }
        },
        "object_story_spec": {
            "page_id": "112232461886043",
            "instagram_actor_id": "9058173320920337"
        },
        "degrees_of_freedom_spec": {
            "creative_features_spec": {
                 "standard_enhancements": {
                 "enroll_status": "OPT_IN"
              }
             }
            },
        "use_page_actor_override": false
}
```

However, I'm receiving an error indicating that the current ad product doesn't support carousel format. I have verified the compatibility of the ad product and reviewed the documentation, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Any solutions here?

Answer (score 1):

I've been updating our current code to comply with v17 of the api and have come across the same "Unsupported format" error with carousel ads.

[FB carousel unsupported format error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTHon.png)

What I have found having looked into the [Standard Enhancements for Advantage+ Creative](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/advantage-catalog-ads/standard-enhancements) change that this api version has introduced is that in the Limitations section on that page it details Carousel ads as not supported.

So in your sample code you need to set the following part that sets up the standard enhancements

```
"degrees_of_freedom_spec": {
        "creative_features_spec": {
             "standard_enhancements": {
             "enroll_status": "OPT_OUT"
         }}}
```

i.e OPT_OUT not OPT_IN

Having tested this change for the ad I was seeing the error with it is now running again.